# JSDoc 3 Document constructor/class parameter

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

How can I document a constructor (function) passed as a parameter?

Example:

```
/** @class */
function A() {}

/**
 * @param {Function} aConstructor
 */
function createA(aClass) {
    return new aClass();
}
```

As you can see, I can specify that it is a function. However, I can't specify which object that function would create. Is there some way to document this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not under `@returns` like `@returns {A}` or if multiple types are possible, you could do `@returns {A|B}}`?

Comment: It appears you may be able to do this with `@constructs <name>` (see the 2nd example at http://usejsdoc.org/tags-constructs.html )

Comment: In this exact case, I would indeed return that data type. However, that doesn't strictly denote that it is the expected data type of the parameter itself. Same with your other example.

Comment: I'd file a request because it doesn't appear to me to support that capability. Using the approach of instanceof, "Function" is the closest for the time being...

Comment: After hunting, I think you are correct. If you want to post that as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I'd file a request because it doesn't appear to me to support that capability. Using the approach of instanceof, "Function" is the closest in representing the object instance for a constructor for the time being. As mentioned, [@constructs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-constructs.html) or `@returns` may be able to help you to indicate the output, but not the parameter input.

Answer (score 9):

Google with its closure propose a {function(new:type)} as a type description.
I've assumed, that one can use something like this (I'm using it with AMD):

```
 /** @param {function(new:ClassOrInterfaceName)} aClass */
```

You can find more information here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#JavaScript_Types

I hope, my answer can help someone )

Comment: Up-to-date and more detailed informatione can be found here: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types

Comment: ... e.g. to allow parameters for the constructor one can use `{function(new:FooBar, string, number)}` etc.